# Dialogflow ES - IOS integration

Tags: swift, dialogflow-es

I was using dialogflow ES v1 with success in my IOS application but i can not find a way to update my API to IOS v2.

I have follow the example:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/dialogflow/stopwatch

but the coacod have an issue with :
No such module 'NIOHTTP1' or 'TinyHTTPServer'

How can i add Dialogflow ES API in my IOS swift app?

Thanks a lot by advance

Benoit